# Algorithm for sorting numbers into bins with variable range

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need to sort a set of n Numbers into "bins" that have a certain range. 
Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
Array = [1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 10]
binA has a range from 1 to 3 -> 1,2 gets sorted in
binB has a range from 4 to 6 -> 4,5,6 gets sorted in
binC has a range from 7 to 10 -> 10 gets sorted in
binD has a range from 11 to 12 -> nothing gets sorted in
```

The bin ranges are defined previously by me, the order of the numbers being put into certain bins do not matter.

Comment: Yep, called bucketsort - you would have to code one with the desired buckets. You could also call any kind of Histogram that preserves the elements per histo as "an algo that does this". That aside - you are asking for kindof offsite resources - I think - at least I do not see any specific problem. Maybe reread  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does "certain range" mean? Are the ranges given to the algorithm, or does it have to somehow dynamically figure some out? Do the numbers have to go into the bins in any particular order? What have you tried and where are you having problems?

Comment: I define the range of the buckets before, the order of numbers going into the bins does not matter. What I tried is simple, 2 for loops, which ended up being a lot too slow of course. I googled a little and came across the Bucket sort as well, but wasn't really sure if this is exactly what I needed. But I will have a closer look at it now.

Comment: Then just go through the array, look at each value, and put it into the appropriate bin. You can get fancy by using a binary search to find the appropriate bin, but that isn't worth the effort if you only have three bins to start with.

Comment: @PatrickArtner - I don't think bucket sort is what OP is doing. The array doesn't need to be sorted, just partitioned into bins.

Comment: @TedHopp after rereading, I think youre right. Buckedsort would only help if  he outputted the buckets before reassembling then in a sorted manner...

Comment: I edited my question, Wouldn't I still need 2 loops for this? Like 'for every value, check every bin till it fits the right one'?

Comment: Yes, you need two loops. The inner loop would be for finding the right bucket and doesn't have to be a linear search loop. If you have many buckets, you order them by range start and use a binary search to find the right one.

Comment: Your logic is unclear. Why does the bin from 1 to 3 get the value 1 sorted into it but the bin from 10 to 12 doesn't get 10 sorted into it?

Comment: My fault, the bin should have started at 11. I will stick with the 2 loops then, the number of bins wont be larger than 20, so I guess this is not really worth the effort. Thank you very much for your help Mr Hopp.

Comment: Two loops are not required. You could create an array `binN` with an element for each possible value in `array` that contains the the bin # for that value. In your example, it would have 12 elements, `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]`. For each element `array[i]`, increment `bin[binN[array[i]]]`.

Comment: @beaker - Well done!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, can you point it out a little further with a detailed example? I dont understand it yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430849/group-array-values-that-are-in-the-same-range-of-multiples-of-10

Comment: Is your confusion because my pseudocode assumed that you simply want to *count* the number of values that go into each bin, and you want to maintain a *list* of the values that are sorted into each bin? If you respond directly to someone's comment, it's helpful if you tag them like @beaker so that they're notified. I don't always go back to check after I've commented. (I didn't have to tag you because you're the post owner.)

Answer (score 0):

If your bins are always of same size (here 3), you can adress the bin by function (Pseudocode):

```
bin = new Array (binA, binB, binC, binD) 

def bin (i: Int) : Int = bin((i+1)/3).add (i)
```

You can create a new class for your Bins (unrelated to above code!):

```
case class Bin (val lo: Int, val hi: Int) {
  override def toString : String = s"from $lo to $hi ${lb} ${if (next == None) "-|" else "\n" + next.get.toString} "
  val lb =  collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] ()
  var next : Option[Bin] = None
  def add (i: Int) {
    if (i < hi)
        lb += i
    else {
        if (next == None) {
            val bin = Bin (hi+1, hi + 4)
            bin.add (i)
            next = Some (bin)
        }
        else next.map (bin => bin.add (i))
    }
  }
}

val sample = List (1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 10)
val binA = Bin (1, 3) 
sample.map (binA.add (_))
println (binA)
```

Result:

```
from 1 to 3 ListBuffer(1, 2) 
from 4 to 7 ListBuffer(5, 6, 4) 
from 8 to 11 ListBuffer(10) -|
```

For different Sizes of Bins, like characters in big encyclopedias (A-B, C-D, E, F-H, ...) you would, of course, need a different way of initialization, but each bin could pass values to the next bin, if it exceeds his bounds.